# Calculating original value after over or under estimating

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

I have simple Maths question and I am interested in exploring its basic operation which I have forgotten from my school days.

I have two values `X` and `Y`. Bath change over a time period and they change by +2M and -2M respectively.

But it turns out I have overestimated the change of X by 11% and underestimated the change of Y by 26%.

What would be the change in them if I correct these "errors"?

Answer (score 0):

The change in x would be 100/111 of what you thought it was, and the change in Y is 100/74 of what you thought it was.